# Why did I get refused of entry into the UK even if I had a sponsorship letter?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

I applied to volunteer at a scout activity center in London,Gilwell Park. I got refused of entry even with a sponsorship letter where it stated that I will have somewhere to.sleep. I would receive a weekly budget and it stated that I would return to.my country after 3 months of stay. Based on some paragraph 46A i got denied... The even took away my right for appeal... I'm a bit afraid to apply again because I don't know what I did wrong in my first application.

Comment: Were you removed from port? Or refused a visa application?  And to clarify, you're under the age of 18?

Comment: Usually they indicate the reason of refusal on your rejection note. What does the rejection say?

Comment: What does paragraphy 46A say...

Comment: @MarkMayo, it doesn't exist any more.  But when it did, it had to do with child visitors.  Surprised to see it showing up in the formulae in fact...

Comment: 46A info here https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423847/Child_visitor_v9.0EXT.pdf

Comment: it might be that volunteer work is considered employment

Comment: @EdmundYeung99, please see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43690/can-a-visitor-to-the-uk-work-as-volunteer

Comment: @gayotflow then that answers it, you are allowed "incidental volunteering" but the op is going specifically for volunteer work which violates the employment clause (volunteering is seen as unpaid work)

Comment: @Džanin try apply for a charitable work visa https://www.gov.uk/tier-5-temporary-worker-charity-worker-visa/overview

Comment: Also, if the scout group receives government subsidies, the allowance they'd provide would possibly be public funds, receival of which is also a violation of 46A

Comment: "Weekly budget" raises red flags for me. You would have to be very clear how a "weekly budget" is different from a "weekly wage".

Comment: @EdmundYeung99, there is no way to tell without reading the refusal formulae. And the OP did not provide it, hence the question is closed as 'Unclear'

Comment: 46A says you must be able to pay for your own accommodation without it being supplied by an employer (or be accommodated by your family).  Since accommodation is part of your employment, this is not met, hence you do not meet the requirement.